# Многострочные комментарии в Python

Tags: python

В Python, для однострочных комментариев используется символ `#`. Но если нужно закомментировать большой блок кода, то приходится приписывать `#` в начале каждой строки. Это очень неудобно при отладке.

Есть ли какая-то возможность использовать многострочные комментарии (аналог `/* ... */` из Си) в Python?

**UPD:**

Знаю, что различные IDE позволяют делать такие вещи автоматически, но хотелось бы более элегантного решения, не зависящего от средства редактирования кода и различных утилит.

Comment: Как это сделать в VIM штатными средствами: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561497

Comment: Мой вопрос сводится скорее к "как использовать многострочные комментарии в языке, где нет многострочных комментариев", а не к "как использовать редакторы кода для автоматического создания пачки однострочных комментариев"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, отдельного синтаксиса для многострочных комментариев в Python нет. В тоже время, можно использовать строковые литералы, заключенные в тройные апострофы, например так:

```python
'''
Это строковый литерал.
Но здесь он используется как многострочный комментарий
'''
```

Строковые литералы, заключенные в тройные кавычки, могут содержать:

- кавычки (`"`)
- апострофы (`'`)
- docstring комментарии (`"""func desc"""`)
- переводы строк

В тоже время, стоит помнить, что такой строковый литерал не должен содержать внутри символов `'''`. Это требование аналогично запрету на последовательность символов `*/` внутри многострочного комментария Си.

Кстати, этот же хак, предлагает использовать создатель языка Python в [одном из своих твитов](https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/112670605505077248).

В тоже время, как верно отметил @jfs, [руководство по стилю кода (pep-8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments) рекомендует использовать `#` для блочных комментариев.

Comment: Действительно, это способ описан во всех (или почти всех) книгах о Python

Answer (score 7):

[Руководство по стилю кода (pep-8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments) рекомендует использовать `#` для блочных комментариев.

> Но если нужно закомментировать большой блок кода, то приходится приписывать # в начале каждой строки. Это очень неудобно при отладке.

Один из явных признаков неумелого программирования -- это наличие закомментированных фрагментов кода. Используйте систему контроля версий и/или ваше IDE, чтобы временно убрать/закомментировать код при отладке. Настройте ваше окружение, чтобы вы могли это делать не задумываясь, нажимая пару клавиш.

> Знаю, что различные IDE позволяют делать такие вещи автоматически, но хотелось бы более элегантного решения, не зависящего от средства редактирования кода и различных утилит.

Закомментированный код не должен добавляться в систему контроля версий, поэтому для временных изменений, которые не переживут одну сессию редактирования кода, один клавишный аккорд (например, M-; в Emacs), как правило, достаточен, чтобы закомментировать/раскомментировать кусок кода.

---

`"""multiline string literal"""` не является многострочным комментарием в Питоне. Это просто строковая константа, которая позволяет использовать буквальные символы новой строки без экранирования (такого как `\n`). Часто используется для описаний модулей, классов, функций/методов прямо в коде:

```
>>> def f():
...     """abc"""
... 
>>> f.__doc__
'abc'
```

Попытка использовать `""""""` в качестве многострочного комментария сломается на первой docstring, даже если бы не было других более подходящий решений для данной задачи.

Comment: IDE, как впрочем и другие редакторы доступны _не во всех средах_. Существует системы где есть только `nano` и нет полномочий установить что-то еще. Я отлично знаю, что в `"""` это не комментарий. Но в python просто _нет другого синтаксиса_ для многострочных комментариев. Собственно я и вопрос-то создал как некий faq, с целью показать хак в языке, а не правильные подходы к разработке, хитрости в обращении с IDE и редакторами и/или VCS.  И еще. Синтаксис `'''` вполне может включать docstring, что я и добавил в свой ответ.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: если вам доступно только `nano`, то спрашивайте вопрос про nano, а не общий вопрос "Многострочные комментарии в Питоне". Даже если Вы используете nano, то `"""` не очень полезно: без подсвечивания синтаксиса Вы даже не увидите, какая строчка закомментирована, а какая нет -- проще просто удалить фрагмент временно.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что вопрос не про редактор. Вопрос про то, как можно использовать многострочные комментарии в языке где нет синтаксиса для многострочных комментариев. Цель этого вопроса-ответа, показать, что способ все-таки есть.

Comment: Как я уже сказал `'''` нормально работает с docstring комментариями.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: `'''` также может быть использован для docstrings (как и любая другая строковая константа). Цель моего ответа, показать, что не нужно использовать `"""` в качестве комментария -- есть лучше методы

Comment: `есть лучше методы` можете привести хоть один, не сводящийся к "используйте фичастый редактор кода"?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: я явно их указал: используйте систему контроля версий, используйте редактор -- если Вы не можете использовать ни то ни другое -- то спрашивайте про Ваши конкретные урезанные обстоятельства -- [программирование, используя только магнитную иголку и твёрдую руку не очень распространено :)](https://xkcd.com/378/)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30196/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-jfs).

Comment: В принципе также можно использовать `#if 0` ... `#endif` и `gcc -E - < prog.py | python` для удаления комментариев перед интерпретацией (шутка, конечно же, **но позволяет делать даже вложенные комментарии**)

Answer (score 4):

В **PyCharm** можно выделить блок который нужно **закомментировать** и нажать Ctrl+/ 
PyCharm в начале каждой строки поставит '#'
Если нужно будет раскоментировать нужно опять же нажать Ctrl+/ и '#' уберутся!
Очень удобно!

Answer (score 3):

Почти все редакторы умеют выделять текст столбцом.

В большинстве из них это делается при помощи Alt+Shift+Стрелка, в редакторах на основе Idea используется переключение по Alt+Shift+Insert между обычным и колоночным режимами.

Я всегда, когда комментирую код, использую однострочные комментарии, выделив нужную группу строк. Это удобно, поскольку во-первых, факт закомментированности не зависит от наличия комментариев в комментируемом коде, а во-вторых, сразу чётко видно единый закомментированный участок кода (при комментировании кнопкой комментария IDE игнорируют пустые строки).

PS: Если код комментируется для долгосрочных целей, то ставлю 4 слеша вместо двух.

Comment: В python конструкция `//` (как и `////`) не является комментарием :) Использование IDE для массового создания однострочных комментариев может быть полезным, но увы не всегда применимо.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, да про слеши я говорил не про питон. Но ведь ставить тем же способом решётку никто не мешает. А использование IDE совсем не обязательно. Текстовые редакторы это тоже умеют. Тот же Notepad++, например.

Comment: Про редакторы: я имел в виду какой-нибудь `mcedit` (`nano`, `vi`, ...) работающий в терминале. Если есть что-то что автоматом проставляет пачку однострочных комментариев, то ваш ответ -- решение. Если нет, то нет :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, надо ж было предупреждать, что линукс с консолью. Уверен, что vim можно как-то заставить это сделать.

Comment: Ну про консоль -- это всего лишь пример. На самом деле оригинальный вопрос сводится к "как использовать многострочные комментарии в python", а не к "как автоматически закомментировать n-строк кода" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Многострочные комментарии в python только с помощью `"""` (три кавычки)